# Flagging history appears at the bottom of page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) It's now fixed and will be live after our next production build.

---

On [my flag page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/72910) the sidebar at the right containing a summary of my flagging history has recently been pushed right to the bottom of the page. I assume it's a bug related to the recent site graduation. I get this using Chrome v46, though I asked in chat and it was in IE11 too.

Here's how it looks:
[image]

Comment: Yea, the most recent Firefox has this as well.

Comment: Chrome off for me too on linux (ubuntu if it matters).

Comment: Repro on Chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: Thank you, we will investigate and fix it asap.

Answer (score 2):

This has now been fixed and works correctly.

Comment: This bug is NOT fixed anymore and [hasn't been for months](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6771/flag-summary-layout-broken). :(

Comment: @BrockAdams Hm, strange. I'm sure it had been working back when I posted this, but is definitely broken for me now.